# ASP.NET Core application can be run in .NET 4.7.2 environment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I built an ASP.NET Core application, but I have a hosting server which allows .NET 4.7.2 version only.

Is it possible to deploy to that environment?

Comment: Refer this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: **No** - .NET Core is its own runtime stack - if you have a **.NET Core** app - you need the **.NET Core** runtime to run it.

Comment: Hello is there anything else that we can help you with? If the given answer was helpful you can accept the answer . You can do that by right clicking on left check mark beside your question [you could have a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)
[How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As @marc_s already said that you cannot run .NET Core on .Net xxx
> run time as two version has it's own runtime and they are different in
> regards of its architecture.

If you have a .NET Core application, depending on its version, you could choose your runtime.

Here is the official release of all [.NET Core versions](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet):

[image]

**Note**

If you have any requirement where you need to communicate both .NET Core xxx version along with the Classic .NET xxx version, there is a way to build a bridge between them that is [.NET Standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0).
The main goal behind .NET Standard was to establish greater uniformity in the .NET ecosystem. You can get more details in [the official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0)

Hope above explanation guided you accordingly.